# PhoneGap for iOS wrap multiple plugins into one plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using phone gap for the iOS now i included "Media" plugin into my project and i want to create a custom plugin of my own in the same project (handle uploading the audio file to server) after all the is done i need to wrap the entire project to one plugin how do i do this?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, you juste have to create your plugin, and in your plugin.xml file you add your dependency to Media plugin.

In your plugin.xml :

```
<platform name="ios">
  <!-- your stuff related to ios for your plugin -->

   <dependency id="org.apache.cordova.media" />
</platform>
```

When your plugin will be added to project, it will check dependencies and install them if needed

Comment: 1st of all thanks for the very quick response if i understand you correctly i start a new project of phone gap create my custom plugin and in there i place the media plugin? can't i just create a project add the media plugin create the custom plugin and wrap it into one?

Comment: Not exactly, I will try to be as clear as possible :)

1) You have an empty project

2) You create your custom plugin, where you specify the dependency in the plugin.xml file

3) You add the plugin : when you add it, Cordova (or Phonegap) reads the plugin.xml file and sees that your custom plugin requires a dependendy. It will then get the dependency and add it (for you it's Media)

Comment: You are welcome :-)
Please take some time to validate answer if you estimate it is the right one

Comment: i will try your way Btw if i just create a project and then add the media plugin and after that i create my custom plugin can i bundle it into one?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to bundle.. is it the media plugin that hs been added to the project, in your plugin ? If so I think it would complicate very much things if you want to distribute your plugin afterwards, and probably not the best way to do it

Comment: Hello Niko now as I'm aware i need to create a cordova plugin thet contains the media plugin and my own custom methods and bundle it into one plugin that someone else will use is it possible? thanks.

Comment: According to StackOverflow guidelines, I recommand you to create new questions for what you are looking for. 
Since it is the way thing work here, again please take some time to validate my answer if it helped you :-)